# Shopware get mainnumber from article

Tags: smarty, shopware

I need to get some attributes from the main article of an article variant. An example:

The user got article SW1234.4 selected. The shop should show the attribute "test" from the main article SW1234 and not from the variant SW1234.4.

I´m thinking about some smarty var with `{$sArticle.mainnumber.attr4}`
How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you should try "{debug}" at first. (Enable popups!)
Now you can see which variables you have access to, maybe the information you are looking for is already stored in a smarty variable.

The Other way would be a custom Plugin which does a select on your articles table and gets the desired information which you than can assign to your view.

e.g.

```
$this->View()->assign($varname, $value);
```

I know my reply is a little late, but I am new to this website as a contributer.

Which Shopware Version?
Are u using the responsive theme?
Please provide a little more information. :)